# How to have multiples scenes with layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, andengine

I am not understanding how to get layouts and multiple scenes (i.e. `org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene`) to work together. The examples I see with layouts work by changing activities & layouts together. As I understand it, having multiple Activities is a bad practice, one should instead have one Activity with multiple scenes, but I don't see how to have a layout with each scene.
So I set use the first layout like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}
```

then a few seconds later comes time to display a menu, but I also read the one is not supposed to call `setContentView()` more than once.
Is it not possible to use layouts AND multiple scenes?

Comment: Having multiple activities is not bad practice. It is pretty much unavoidable for all but the most basic apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "scenes", but having multiple activities is pretty much how all Android apps work. You may want to take a look at Fragments, if you want to have just one activity:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Depends on your exact project, but I agree - highly suggest looking into Fragments.

Comment: By "scene" I mean `org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene`

Comment: I've read the Fragments documentation now. While Scene and Fragments are not equivalent, I can see how I can accomplish what I need to do with Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to use multiple layouts and multiple scenes in single activity by calling

> setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

where ever you want

Comment: Possible, but not recommended.   Having multiple activities is a much better approach.  The entire Android user interface support system is built around the idea that you will have a separate activity for each separate screen you display.  Whoever told you that having multiple activities was bad practice was wrong.